# Pdf preview with imageMagick in php

Tags: php, css, html, pdf, preview

I am looking for the simplest way of generating image preview from the first page of a pdf file. I have found a nice [tutorial](https://webvamp.co.uk/blog/webvamp/how-to-create-pdf-preview-images-in-php-part-2/), however the code is not complete there. What is the missing part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ImageMagick from PHP exec()

```
exec("convert -density XX image.pdf[0] -resize YY% preview.png")
```

where XX is the desired density (nominal is 72) but I use something like 288=4*72) to get good quality and YY is the corresponding percent to reduce the image, such as 25%. The [0] means to process only the first page of the pdf.

```
exec("convert -density 288 image.pdf[0] -resize 25% preview.png")
```

Adjust these arguments to get the desired output size. You can change png to jpg, but you should then add -quality ZZ before the output to set the jpg compression quality. Values are 0 to 100, nominal for ImageMagick is to use 92.